# How to display parameters passed to a component and how to give optional parameters to a component in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, asp.net-core, react-router-v4

I am developing a web page using react with typescript in visual studio 2017 and am very new to it. I am having some trouble accessing the parameters passed to a component and making a parameter optional. Below is my code:-

routes.tsx:

```
export const routes = <Layout>
<Switch>
    <Route path='/home/:id' component={Home} /> //<= this works, but i want id parameter to be optional. I tried (/:id) but the component does not render if i do this.
</Switch>
</Layout>
```

Home.tsx:

```
export class Home extends React.Component<RouteComponentProps<{}>, {}> {
public render() {
    console.log(this.props.match.params); //<= I can see the id which i pass in the console
    return <div>
       <h1>{this.props.match.params}<h1> //<= this does not work and gives me a runtime error 'Unhandled rejection Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {id}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead or wrap the object using createFragment(object) from the React add-ons'
   </div>
```

1)How do i provide optional parameters to a component?
2)How do i display the passed parameter in Home component?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Add another `<Route path='/home' component={Home} />`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `?` as said by @pgsandstrom to pass an optional parameter worked for me.

As far as retrieving the id property from params what i did was create an object for this.props.match.params and then use that object to retrieve the id. Following is the code i used:-

```
let data = Object.create(this.props.match.params);
```

and then

```
data.id
```

will retrieve my id without giving any compilation errors in typescript

Comment: What you are doing here is just removing the type safety of typescript by obscuring the type of the object. If you dont want type safety there are better ways of doing it. You could write `const noTypeSafety = this.props.match.params as any` instead. Or simply use javascript instead of typescript. There are however better but more verbose solutions that has type safety.

Answer (score 2):

Use a `?` like this to pass an optional parameter:

`<Route path="/home/:id?" component={Home}/>`

[Start reading here](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/path-string) to find out more

To display the variable, use `{this.props.match.params.id}`. If you want to handle the case when id is not present, something like this can be used:

`{this.props.match.params.id || 'sorry lol no id is specified'}`

To clarify why you get an error: "params" is an object that holds all parameters. React does not know how to display an object. If you want to display an object, you could use `JSON.stringify(params)` but I dont think that is what you're looking for.

Comment: Okay the optional params works now. But this.props.match.params.id gives me a compile time error Property 'id' does not exist on type {}. How do i solve  this? Please note that i am using typescript

Comment: @PrasaadPatil create a separate question for it with some code examples and I'll have a look.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you want to render Object because this.props.match.params points to whole object, so you either have to stringify or ask for certain property like Id.

```
{JSON.stringify(this.props.match.params)}
```

or

```
{this.props.match.params.id}
ofcourse that for this thing you have to accept id as parametr /home/:id
```

Since you are using typescript it depends if you are writing class(Component) or function, either way the error you are geting is because you havent typed it correctly, but since you are reffering to this.props, I will assume its class.

```
class App extends React.Component<Props> {}

interface Props {
    match: any;
}
```

Yes its weak typing, but unless you import typing directly from the library, it would take you a while to type the whole thing, plus doing it in each file would be stupid.

Comment: But how can i get id without using stringify? this.props.match.params.id gives me a compile time error Property 'id' does not exist on type {}. How do i solve this? Please note that i am using typescript

Comment: You probably typed match as simple object, or params as simple object, either way now its just wrong typing nothing else.

Comment: After your class definition you have pair of these <> between them you have to type props and state. You have put there empty objects, so either go with Props and write interface for it, or if you cant be bothered write <any, any> but in that case there is no reason to use typescript.